# Meteor throwing unusual errors in browser console

Tags: reactjs, npm, meteor

[image: error pic]

I am working on meteor reactjs project. Previously it was running fine, but suddenly I am started to getting this error.

Pic shown above are the errors I am getting in browser. I cannot load my project in browser even though I can't see any error on meteor run command prompt.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you install any npm packages right before this error started occurring?

Comment: We'll need to see your code. Have you already been able to create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: piggybacking off of @KellyCopley answer. Be sure to install your project dependencies using meteor node version instead of the version currently on your device. So `meteor npm install` instead of `npm install`.

Comment: Thank you all. I changed machine meteor version to repository meteor version. npm installed and restarted meteor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

The project repository is using meteor version 1.8.1.
And my laptop .meteor.bat file was pointing to 1.12.0 meteor version.

I changed meteor version 1.12.0 to 1.8.1 in .bat file from AppData folder of C folder.

Then npm install and restart meteor project.

This removed all exceptions from browser console and my web page started working